# Can I use a persons web behaviour to affect journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, web

Can I use the web behaviour of a known user to impact on journey builder in Marketing Cloud (I assume I need some tracking code installed??).

some use cases would be:

1. We've sent a user an email.  If within 3 days they've not visited
   page  then send them a reminder.  If they've visited page 
   then send them info about page
2. A known user has visited page .  Send an email two days later
   with some related information.

If the answers to the above are yes - then how :)

Cheers
Jo

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your journey for use case 1 as follows:

1. Create entry source(suitable to your scenario. It might be a data
   extension or Audience or whatever), followed by your email.
2. Put a wait activity for 3 days.
3. Use an engagement split with 'message metrics' as 'Clicks' and on true path 
   configure your email with info about the link and on false path send reminder.

Please clarify how do you mark your user as know user. Are you calling one who has already clicked on the link as your know user. And is this user visiting your page(I am assuming Landing Page) by again clicking on the link provided in your email or how else. Please provide more details.

Comment: krati, 
your example sort works for the first use case (although couldn't be used to monitor the download of a PDF for example, as that wouldn't be a click from the email).  

For my second use case, assume the user has logged in.  

It feels like I need to be able to do web tracking and have decisions made about information returned from that.  That is how I'd solve this problem in other tools I've used.